# Finding substring in a string using perl

Tags: perl

Below is the code

```
$string = "any text
Affected area :
menu

Feature to test :

diagnostics
";

$string1=rindex($string,':');
print "$string1\n";

$string2=substr($string,$string1+1);
print "$string2";
```

I can able to find the string after "Feature to test" using above code but i want to find the string which is for Affected area eg. menu.Please help

Comment: use Perl's debugger as `perl -d your_script.pl` and apply break-point in your code, this way you can figure out what is mssing in you regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I take that this is a test program of some sort. Would doing this this way make more sense?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $feature_to_test;
my $affected_area;
while ( my $line <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /^Affected area\s*:/i ) {
        for (;;) {  #Loop forever (until I tell you to stop i.e.)
            my $line = <DATA>;
            if ( $line !~ /^\s*$/ ) {
               $affected_area = $line;
               last;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $line =~ /^Affected area\s*:/i ) {
        for (;;) {  #Loop forever (until I tell you to stop i.e.)
            my $line = <DATA>;
            if ( $line !~ /^\s*$/ ) {
               $affected_area = $line;
               last;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $line =~ /^Feature to test\s*:/i ) {
        for (;;) {  #Loop forever (until I tell you to stop i.e.)
            my $line = <DATA>;
            if ( $line !~ /^\s*$/ ) {
               $feature_to_test = $line;
               last;
            }
        }
    }

}
else {
    print qq("Not a special line: "$line"\n);
}

__DATA__
any text
Affected area :
menu

Feature to test :

diagnostics
```

The advantage of this method is that it allows you to test line-by-line instead of trying to parse the entire record at once. Plus, it better emulates the way a file would be read in.

It's also possible to use `split` to split your long text into an array that you could also go through line by line too:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "any text
Affected area :
menu

Feature to test :

diagnostics
";
my @string_list = split /\n/, $string;  #Now, this is split line by line
for my $line ( @string_list ) {
    print "same logic as above...\n";
}
```

Doing this as a loop and reading in each line makes the logic a bit cleaner and easier to understand. It's probably not as efficient, but even reading in a multi-million line file in Perl doesn't take more than a few seconds even on an econo-box PC.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a regex using a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a capture will be helpful here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "any text
Affected area :
menu

Feature to test :

diagnostics
";

my ($area) = $string =~ /(?<=area :\n)(.+)/;

print $area;
```

Output:

```
menu
```

Comment: I am using the same command to get the string after Feature to test : eg diagnostics like my ($test) = $string =~ /(?<=test :\n)(.+)/; i am getting Use of uninitialized value $test1 in print. Why?

Comment: @user1891916 - There are two newlines after `test :`, so try `/(?<=test :\n\n)(.+)/`.